# How to get Vera++ to ignore sections of code for some/all rules?

Tags: c++, static-analysis, vera++

I am using [Vera++](https://bitbucket.org/verateam/vera/wiki/Home) to perform some static analysis on my C++ code. (in Visual Studio 2008)

However, I have some blocks of code that I know, and accept, will break certain rules.

I'd like to be able to somehow tell Vera++ to avoid these methods or sections of code, so the reports show only the areas of code that I want to adjust.

Is there anything I can put into my code, eg a specially formatted comment, that would allow certain blocks of code to ignore certain rules?

Comment: In the [documentation](https://bitbucket.org/verateam/vera/wiki/Running) I have only found a `--exclusions` option that only allows to exclude _entire C++ source files_, not sections of code. There seems to be a [feature request](https://bitbucket.org/verateam/vera/issue/23/add-advanced-exclusion-mechanism) for a more advanced exclusion mechanism...

Answer (score 5):

As gx_ said, `--exclusions` allow you to skip some files for specified rules. Click [here](https://bitbucket.org/verateam/vera/wiki/Running) for more information.

But it can not work for specified code snippet.

And [here](https://bitbucket.org/verateam/vera/issue/23/add-advanced-exclusion-mechanism) is an issue for vera asking for an enhance what you wanted, you can pay some attention on it.